# How can I change the background color of my MainActivity from a second activity using colored buttons as user choices?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a program with more than one activity. From my MainActivity I can click a button which will send the user to the ThirdActivity_ColorPicker. In the third activity I have three buttons, named colors, when clicked should change the background color of the MainActivity. Except, it is not changing the background color.

In MainActivity I have an Intent which switches me to the third activity.

```
private View.OnClickListener changeToColorPickerActivity = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      Intent goToThirdActivityColorPicker = new Intent(getApplication(), ThirdActivity_ColorPicker.class);
      startActivityForResult(goToThirdActivityColorPicker, COLOR_PICKER_REQUEST);
    }
  };
```

In my third activity I have the three buttons, red, blue, and green, which when clicked should change the MainActivity background color to the selected color.

```
  private View.OnClickListener changeMainActivityToBlue = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      Intent intentBlue = new Intent();
      setResult(RESULT_CODE_BLUE, intentBlue);
      finish();
    }
  };
```

Back in MainActivity I have an onActivityResult to receive data from the thrid activity

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    thirdAct = new ThirdActivity_ColorPicker();

    if(requestCode == RESULT_OK && resultCode == thirdAct.RESULT_CODE_RED){
      constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_layout).setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.redBackground));
    }else if(requestCode == RESULT_OK && resultCode == thirdAct.RESULT_CODE_GREEN){
      constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_layout).setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.greenBackground));
    }else if(requestCode == RESULT_OK && resultCode == thirdAct.RESULT_CODE_BLUE){
      constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.blueBackground));
    }
  }
```

Result I would like is for the background color to change with the code above, but used correctly because I know I am doing something wrong somewhere.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ThirdActivity_ColorPicker`, change the code on each of your color button click, that is (Red, Green, Blue, etc), as below. This will set the Bundle data and result for the previous activity.

```
 Intent intentRed = new Intent();
 intentRed.putExtra(COLOR_CODE, 
 getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.redBackground));
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intentRed);
 finish();
```

Then, in your `MainActivity`, in `onActivityResult`, make below changes:

```
 if (requestCode == COLOR_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
   if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
      Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
      int colorBg = bundle.getInt(COLOR_CODE);
      findViewById(R.id.mainBg).setBackgroundColor(colorBg);
    }
 }
```

`COLOR_PICKER_REQUEST` is the `int`, which you set for the `startActivityForResult` and `COLOR_CODE` is any `String` for the bundle key.

Comment: I am confused by the COLOR_CODE in my third activity. How do I set it? It yells at me if I set it as an int, but if I set it as a string then MainActivity yells at me because it is not an int.

Comment: Never mind, I changed COLOR_CODE to "COLOR_CODE"  and it worked for me. I am to literal sometimes. Thank YOU!!!